# How to empty value of file upload after validation is failed?

Tags: file, upload

I have a file input field to upload image and is validated using JQuery. But if validation fail, it still upload the file selected on submit. Is there any way to clear or reset file field if validation fail?

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">


$('#file').change(function(){
        var ext = $('#file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','pdf']) == -1) {
            alert('Please make sure the types of file allowed to upload are jpg, jpeg, png, gif or pdf only');
        }
        if (this.files[0].size > 2097152) {             
            alert('Your file size is larger then allowed file size limit of 2MB');          
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can not set the value of a file input for security reasons. Calling the reset method of the form should clear it, but that would reset everything else as well. I think the easiest way would be to replace the input field in the DOM with a new one.

Comment: Got it but $('#file').replaceWith($('#file').clone()); also does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Once the validation is failed set the value of file to,

```
$('#file').val("");
```